# Macro to run through 3 conditions and provide value

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first time using VBA for Excel (I usually code Java and C++), and I was hoping to get some tips to start out.

I want to write a macro for a large data set that will proceed through the following list of conditions to provide a dollar result:

1. Collect unit size from column A (Possible values 0-8)
2. Determine whether single or family unit from Column B (Single- 1, Family- 0)
3. Collect utility code from Column C (code for type of product being assessed)

From this information, a new value will be placed in the row which determines utility costs by taking into account unit size, type of unit, and the product in question. I have thought about using nested `Select Case` or nested conditionals in a loop, but overall I am pretty lost.

Comment: To get started, use the macro recorder to do what you want manually in Excel. Then see what code you get. That will teach you some simple VBA. You can use that with looping / select case - since you understand those concepts. See how far you get. Then if you are stuck, post some code and tell us where you are stuck. We can help you much better that way! :) For more info on asking questions, see http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a worksheet formula might do the trick, but it's hard to tell without knowing what the calculation is.  Below is a user-defined function (UDF) that you would put in a standard module.  You would call it from a cell like:

```
=computecosts(A2,B2,C2)
```

Obviously the code would change depending on how your data is laid out and what your calculation is.

```
Public Function ComputeCosts(rSize As Range, rFamily As Range, rCode As Range) As Double

    Dim lSizeFactor As Long
    Dim lFamilyFactor As Long
    Dim dCodeFactor As Double
    Dim rFound As Range

    Const lFAMILY As Long = 0

    'Size factor is a function of 0-8, namely adding 1
    lSizeFactor = rSize.Value + 1

    'Family factor is computed in code
    If rFamily.Value = lFAMILY Then
        lFamilyFactor = 3
    Else
        lFamilyFactor = 2
    End If

    'Code factor is looked up in a different sheet
    Set rFound = Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(1).Cells.Find(rCode.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        dCodeFactor = rFound.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If

    'do the math
    ComputeCosts = lSizeFactor * lFamilyFactor * dCodeFactor

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses, they were helpful in understanding VBA for Excel. I just ended up putting possible values in a table and then using Match functions within an Index function to pick out the right value.

Comment: In that case it would be polite (and good for your reputation) to accept Dick's answer